# Error publishing test results to Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I build and test NET 6 app in docker which works well - I see test output in console. When I try to publish test results I encounter an error. Full task output:

> Starting: Publish test results
> ============================================================================== Task         : Publish Test Results Description  : Publish test
> results to Azure Pipelines Version      : 2.170.1 Author       :
> Microsoft Corporation Help         :
> https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results
> ============================================================================== /usr/bin/dotnet --version
> 3.1.418 Async Command Start: Publish test results Publishing test results to test run '22493988' Test results remaining: 65. Test run
> id: 22493988

**> ##[warning]Failed to publish test results: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'TestResult.tbl_TestCaseReference' with unique index**

> 'ix_TestCaseReference2'. The duplicate key value is (1, 3559, 0, 0, 0,
> 0x2b12334e709060df7748bee70b2472ff22c0b671ae3e3b997395858711e5eef5,
> 0x89d7d75814a51ce876ec351fcb9aec22313feeece07fb1d5a3023a3e7a1f634d,
> UnitTest, 0, 0, ). Async Command End: Publish test results Finishing:
> Publish test results

Copy test results and publish steps

```
- pwsh: |
    $id=docker images --filter "label=test=$(Build.BuildId)" -q | Select-Object -First 1
    docker create --name testcontainer $id
    docker cp testcontainer:/testresults ./testresults
    docker rm testcontainer
  displayName: 'Copy test results'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'VSTest'
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/testresults'
  displayName: 'Publish test results'
```

Copy tests results without errors:

> Starting: Copy test results
> ============================================================================== Task         : PowerShell Description  : Run a PowerShell script on
> Linux, macOS, or Windows Version      : 2.170.1 Author       :
> Microsoft Corporation Help         :
> https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
> ============================================================================== Generating script.
> ========================== Starting Command Output =========================== /usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/vsts/agent/_work/_temp/20d795dd-e081-4216-b9b1-327d257bbcb2.ps1'
> 69ba144bfd471794f0e11047a2b214bd7190b96b5b47616957927125c740f266
> testcontainer
>
> Finishing: Copy test results

I took code from tutorial: https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/run-xUnit-inside-docker-during-ci-build

Answer (score 0):

- The xunit test publisher may be an issue here.
- Try resolving the error by t by changing `Xunit` to `VSTest`.
- And also, you don't necessarily need a separate Publish Test Results job in the pipeline because built-in tasks like the Visual Studio Test task automatically publish test results to the pipeline.

Please refer this MSFT doc [Publish Test Results task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx,yaml) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted my colleagues and turns out it's a bug in Azure. I replaced VSTest publisher and format with XUnit publisher and XML format - the XML was successfully uploaded. Another issue was that XML was only for one project in solution, so I ended up dropping that step all together because I don't really need this information anyway (if test failed, so fails build).